# Use IIS Outbound Rewrites in C# or VB.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, iis, web-config

Using IIS URL Rewrite one can rewrite URLs at response time in IIS. I want to be able to do this from codebehind so that I can save a file with rewritten URLs (such as sitemap.xml). Is this possible in VB/C#? I can't seem to find any built in way to do this.

Alternatively, is there any way with Outbound rules through IIS to ReWrite URLs that are inside the innerHTML of a specific html item, and not an attribute?

I've started to write my own .NET class to do this (load rewrites from web.config on class instantiation, the call a function passing the unwritten URL to receive back a rewritten one), but while the basic solution to get simpler rewrites working is quite trivial, the complete solution doesn't seem to be trivial at all.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the answer here:

http://forums.iis.net/t/1163122.aspx?Rewriting+javascript+code+possible

> You can rewrite the links within the javascript code by using outbound
>   rewrite without specifiy the matching scope. The rule looks like:
>
> ```
>  <rule name="Rewrite internal link">
>            <match filterByTags="None" customTags="" pattern="https://internal/" />
>             <action type="Rewrite" value="https://extenal/" />
>  </rule>
> ```